# How to show that the point $I$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle I_AI_BI_C$

Tags: geometry

In the image, I need to prove that $I$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle I_AI_BI_C$.

[image]

One way I thought about it is to show that $\overline{I_AA}$ is perpendicular to $\overline{I_BI_C}$ and that $\overline{I_CC}$ is perpendicular to the line $\overline{I_AI_B}$, and so on, but I don't know how to start. Any help will be appreciated, much thanks.

Comment: Note that $I$ and $I_A$ are on the *internal* bisector of $\angle A$, and that $I_B$ and $I_C$ are on the *external* bisector.

Comment: @Blue I think you should make it an answer.

Comment: @krishan What it has got to do with this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $I$ and $I_A$ are on the *internal* bisector of $\angle A$, and that $I_B$ and $I_C$ are on the *external* bisector.